# Create TextBox with two different formatting

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a org.apache.poi.hslf.model.TextBox that has two different types of formattings. I want some of the text to be size 14 and bold, and the rest to be size 10 and not bold.

I've tried something along the lines of this:

```
TextRun run = textBox.createTextRun();
run.setText("small text"\n);

TextRun run = textBox.createTextRun();
RichTextRun format = run.getRichTextRuns()[0];
format.setBold(true);
format.setFontSize(14);
run.setText("big text");
```

However, only the "big text" shows up.

Does anyone know how to do this. I would really like to keep this to one TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `TextRun.appendText()` instead of calling `TextRun.createTextRun()` twice, because the 2nd call will overwrite the first instance.

```
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.*;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.*;

public class HslfTextBox {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow();
        Slide s = ppt.createSlide();
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(100,100,100,100));
        TextRun run = txt.createTextRun();
        RichTextRun rtr1 = run.getRichTextRuns()[0];
        rtr1.setText("small text\n");
        rtr1.setFontSize(10);
        RichTextRun rtr2 = run.appendText("big text\n");
        rtr2.setBold(true);
        rtr2.setFontSize(14);
        s.addShape(txt);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("hssftext.ppt"); 
        ppt.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "setText()"overwrites the text set before, as result you can see only the last set text. In order to add any additional text after the existing text use "appendText()".